# How to use firebase auth to manage access to existing API (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to find the way to screw down the firebase auth (we have our working example: https://maksimpegov.github.io/portal/login, source code: https://github.com/MaksimPegov/portal/tree/master/src/app) to my existing API built with node js ([Running app](http://happy-happy.193b.starter-ca-central-1.openshiftapps.com)). It use passport auth now (not fully finished). My plan is to switch auth to firebase and rewrite frontend from angularjs to angular. So I whant to keep my hosting and API on Nodejs (hosted with OpenShift) and use firebase auth to manage user access to that API. Please shere your thought and ideas how to implement this, shere the links to nice examples if you have them. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you'd:

1. Let the users sign in with Firebase Authentication normally
2. Securely send their ID token to your server
3. Verify the ID token on your server

The entire process is documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens